# Spring roo could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, transactions, spring-roo

I'm managing a project with Spring roo, and i'm using hibernate, when i try to use this controller methode i have this exception message: could not initialize proxy - no Session

```
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
com.macrosystem.rentacar.service.DefaultJournalService.getReservationsProfitPerYear(DefaultJournalService.java:142)
com.macrosystem.rentacar.service.DefaultJournalService.getTotalLossAndProfitPerYear(DefaultJournalService.java:159)
com.macrosystem.rentacar.service.DefaultJournalService.getTotalLossAndProfit(DefaultJournalService.java:173)
com.macrosystem.rentacar.web.JournalController.lossAndPorfit(JournalController.java:44)
```

Here is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/lossandprofit.json")
public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Number>> lossAndPorfit(){
  return journalService.getTotalLossAndProfit() ;
}
```

and the service method that cause the exception

```
@Override
@Transactional
public BigDecimal getReservationsProfitPerYear(int year) {
    BigDecimal reservationsprofit = new BigDecimal(0) ;
    if(vehicle == null){
        log.warn("vehicule is null") ;
    }
    Set<Reservation> reservations = vehicle.getReservations() ;
    Iterator<Reservation> iterator = reservations.iterator() ;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Reservation current = iterator.next() ;
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar() ;
        calendar.setTime(current.getStartDate()) ;
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){
            reservationsprofit = reservationsprofit.add(current.getAmount()) ;
        }
    }
    return reservationsprofit;
}
```

Why i have that exception even if i annotate my service method with @Transactionnal, i looked at the applicationContext.xml file and found this line

```
 <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

is it the mode="aspectj" part that cancel the effect of that annotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error and after reading this [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777285/no-session-proxy-in-hibernate-and-spring) I added the following to my web.xml which solved the problem:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jpaOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jpaOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```